# Regex Date Validation Format

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, date

Can anyone help me how to change the date format of this jquery validation from YYYY-MM-DD to MM/DD/YYYY.

Example:

```
2014-02-21 must be 02/21/2014
```

I tried to change this: `new RegExp(/^(\d{4})[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/);`

To: `new RegExp(/^((0?[13578]|10|12)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[01]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1}))|(0?[2469]|11)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[0]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1})))$/);`

But still I can't get the right validation I want..

Here's the code:

```
            "date": {
                //  Check if date is valid by leap year
        "func": function (field) {
                var pattern = new RegExp(/^(\d{4})[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/); //<---- The Original Pattern of YYYY-MM-DD
                var match = pattern.exec(field.val());
                if (match == null)
                   return false;

                var year = match[1];
                var month = match[2]*1;
                var day = match[3]*1;
                var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day); // because months starts from 0.

                return (date.getFullYear() == year && date.getMonth() == (month - 1) && date.getDate() == day);
            },
         "alertText": "* Invalid date, must be in YYYY-MM-DD format"
            }
```

Please help me.. thanks.. :)

Comment: Why do people think that regexp is the best way to validate dates? Just split it into numbers and then test the range.

Comment: I'm just a beginner sir. I just want to know how to change the format from the basics. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this.

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/^\d{4}-((0\d)|(1[012]))-(([012]\d)|3[01])$/);
```

But this wont check for the days in a month for example 31 Feb. But it would be a length way to do that with a RegEx.

Comment: It still didn't work for me, I think there are some code that needs to change

 var year = match[1];
                var month = match[2]*1;
                var day = match[3]*1;
                var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day); // because months starts from 0.

                return (date.getFullYear() == year && date.getMonth() == (month - 1) && date.getDate() == day);

Comment: Why is the month starting from 0?

Answer (score 0):

#### Months

```
(0?[1-9]|1[012])
```

#### Days

```
(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

#### Years

```
(19|20)?[0-9]{2}
```

Flaws:

- Will match Feb 29-31, Dec 31, etc.

Answer (score 0):

try the following regular expression

note that it just check only the format didn't check is the year is leap year or not

```
function validateDate(testDate){    

    var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ ;
    return date_regex.test(testDate);

        }
```